# Android Swipe gesture and item click both not working together in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-calendar, swipe-gesture

I have calendar implemented using recyclerview. For navigation to previous and next month, as per requirement, client wants to swipe feature.

So I implemented that feature using this code:

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(context) {
        public void onSwipeTop() {

        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
            onPreviousMonth();
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            onNextMonth();
        }

        public void onSwipeBottom() {

        }
    });
```

Using this touchListener, its working completely swipe feature for the calendar.

> But after adding this feature, click of the recyclerview item not
>   working. When I remove touch listener, click of the recyclerview item working
>   perfectly.

What I missed in the code? Any idea? Both are not working together.

And this is OnSwipeTouchListener:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom();
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop();
                }
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider attaching an [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper) to your RecyclerView.

Implementation is something like this:

```
new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                onPreviousMonth();
            } else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                onNextMonth();
            }
        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much. I owe a KitKat to you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add logic like this,

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1 = event.getX();
                y1 = event.getY();
                t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2 = event.getX();
                y2 = event.getY();
                t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2 && (t2 - t1) < DURATION_TO_CONSIDER_CLICK) {
                    // Consider as normal click or tap
                } else if ((t2 - t1) >= DURATION_TO_CONSIDER_CLICK) {
                    // Consider as long click or tap
                } else if (x1 > x2) {
                    // Consider as left swipe
                } else if (x2 > x1) {
                    // Consider as right swipe
                } 
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Please note that this is just for the reference, you might need to change the above logic as bit to fulfill your expectation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the `TouchListener` is not *consuming* the touch event. If you return true from the onTouch() method, Android will consider it consumed and not pass it on to the other various touch handlers (which I am assuming will include the `ClickListener`).

Comment: Thanks @Anjan I have already tried this but not working. I have to swipe twice to change a month. It's not working on a single swipe.